# Query to filter the pages with word typed in the search box in sharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, query

Below query is bringing all the results instead of filtered results for the pages 
in SharePoint Online:

```
var queryUrl = "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + term + "'" + &trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=4&sourceid='" + "5e34578e-4d08-4edc-8bf3-002acf3cdbcc" + "'"


Search With SharePoint Local
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the Same Search: Pages as `ResultSource`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try your query using [this](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) tool.  If it still returns everything, then you need to change your query.

Comment: I did .. it is even me error 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'

Comment: Did you log in at the bottom?

Comment: Now its working.. has problem with settings but still it shows all results for the query

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the syntax formatting issues? Try the following:

```
 var queryUrl = "/_api/search/query?" + "querytext='" + term + "'" + "&sourceid='5e34578e-4d08-4edc-8bf3-002acf3cdbcc'" + "&rowlimit=4" + "&trimduplicates=false";
```